# How can I solve this time format not working antd and dayjs?

Tags: reactjs, antd, dayjs

I am now updating the old code base.

I am getting the error from `time picker` which is antd component using `dayjs` format

Here is the time picker

```
        <TimePicker
          name="time"
          id="cron-week-time"
          value={values.time}
          onChange={(value) => {
            setFieldValue('time', value);
          }}
          defaultValue={dayjs('00:00', timeFormat)}
          format='HH:mm'
          showNow={false}
        />
```

As you can see I am getting invalid date at the start and I can't select the hour and second[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to antd `TimePicker` component's [documentation](https://ant.design/components/time-picker/), you can use `moment` for time.

In case you want to use `dayjs` (to reduce bundle size maybe), the documentation has a guide to replace `moment` in that case. You can check [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/replace-moment).